Problema al llamar a una función en JavaScript: "Uncaught ReferenceError: function is not defined"
Estoy aprendiendo JavaScript y me he encontrado con un problema al intentar definir y llamar una función. He creado una función que toma dos números y devuelve su suma. Sin embargo, cuando intento llamar a la función, recibo un error "Uncaught ReferenceError: function is not defined". Aquí está el código que estoy usando:


function sumarNumeros(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}

let resultado = sumarNumeros(3, 4);
console.log(resultado);



El error aparece en la consola del navegador cuando intento ejecutar este código. He verificado que la función esté definida antes de llamarla, pero sigo recibiendo el error.
¿Alguien podría ayudarme a entender por qué ocurre este error y cómo puedo solucionarlo? ¡Gracias de antemano!

Si ejecutas el código que has puesto ahí verás que imprime 7 en la consola sin ningún error. Así que casi que te recomiendo que revises que en tu código original has escrito el nombre de la función correctamente... mayúsculas y minúsculas incluidas! O eso, o hay algo más que no nos estás contando. Si tienes la función declarada dentro de algún bloque (un if por ejemplo) esta no será accesible fuera de dicho bloque (a esto se le llama scope)

He votado para cerrar, pero te dejo cosas que comprobar: ¿La función se declara en el mismo script en el que se llama? Si no es así, comprueba que el orden de declaración de los scripts es el correcto
